# Sql query that uses range already inputted into database and matches it with a unique identifier on the table to avoid duplication

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a query that will avoid duplicating entry into the database(uses range of numbers already inputted into the database and flags error when the range that already exist is typed in matching that range to job_no).

```
id | user_id | startNo | endNo | start_date | client_name| job_no |job_quantity|  status                            
1  |    4    |    1    | 1950  | 2014-05-13 |   bixx     | t50000 | n4500      |nt signed 
2  |    2    |   1951  | 4500  | 2014-05-13 |   bixx     | t50000 | n4500      |signed off 3  |    1    |    1    | 3000  | 2014-05-14 |   THT      | t42100 | n7000      |nt signed
4  |    4    |   3001  | 4010  | 2014-05-14 |   THT      | t42100 | n7000      |nt signed
5  |    3    |   4011  | 6500  | 2014-05-14 |   THT      | t42100 | n7000      |nt signed
6  |    6    |   6501  | 7000  | 2014-05-15 |   THT      | t42100 | n7000      |signed off
7  |    1    |    1    | 4000  | 2014-05-16 |   FIBB     | t10000 | n4000      |signed off
```

users can't start a job below the endNo range that has already been done for a particular job_no. job_no been the unique identifier.
it will be an INSERT query.

There will be multiple users working on same job (with unique job_no per job), so lets say there are 4500 jobs to be done and user 4 picks job 1 to 1950. I am just looking for a way to avoid duplicating jobs so that user 2 compulsorily starts from 1951 and not start anywhere below 1950. if user 2 attempts to do so it should flag an error.

number cannot be within the lower range already given. for any specific job, if there is a range of 1 to 40 then you cannot add another row to the table for that job with the range starting between the 1 to 40.

I am not very good with sored procedure so indepth explanation is required as per writing the insert query or stored procedure.

Comment: is the `job_range` a string or numbers in the database?

Comment: Also what are you looking for? an insert query? a select query?

Comment: The key to your query appears to be "*or less*" in the phrase "same job range or less". Above @John has asked the critical question, as how the "or less" is dealt with depends upon how the values are stored. And It would appear that it is stored as a VARCHAR, while you want to process it as two numerics so you can make the "or less" comparison.

Comment: Also, your example says `user_id=4` can't insert `1-300` for `t42100`, but that is already shown in the example table??? And how should overlapping ranges be handled? There can only one row with a given `job_no` in any overlapping ranges? However, rows `id=1` and `id=2` overlap on `3000` unless you stipulate that the ending number of a range is not included in the range.

Comment: so what he is saying is your number cannot be within the lower range already given. for any specific job, if there is a range of 1-40 then you cannot add another row to the table for that job with the range starting between the 1-40

Comment: I have most of it done, but I want to know what exactly the OP wants for a query... i can do a select to check for that if thats what he's looking for.. just not clear in the question

Comment: @John Yes, the SQL itself is not difficult - it is writing the *correct* SQL to solve the *actual* problem, given that it has been stated a little imprecisely. I won't put in an answer if you are working on one, unless it turns out that I am thinking of something entirely different than you.

Comment: yea exactly... just waiting for a response.

Comment: job_range is a number in the database and as for the example shown in the table, user_id 4 and job range 1-300 shouldnt be there, just using it for illustration sake. and yes I am looking for an insert query. there will be multiple users working on same job, so lets say there are 5000 jobs to be done and user 1 picks job 1-3000. I am just looking for a way to avoid duplicating jobs so  that user 2 does not log in and start from 2000-4000 which means he/she would have duplicated 1000 jobs already done by user 1.